# Extracting text between a character and space

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this text and I want to extract the id of collector that is bolded

knowing that the id is not fixed it May 5 digits or even three digits

EX:

```
'Date:20190303 Collector:**4840** U:98611 COLLECTION A 647659 N'
```

what is the best approach to do that by oracle functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `REGEXP_SUBSTR` as follows:

```
SQL> with YOUR_DATA as
  2  (select 'Date:20190303 Collector:4840 U:98611 COLLECTION A 647659 N' as str
  3     from dual)
  4  -- Your query starts
  5  SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, 'Collector:([^ ]+)',1,1,NULL,1)
  6  FROM YOUR_DATA;

REGE
----
4840

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you, you’re amazing! it is exactly what I needed. it is working fine

Comment: Welcome!! You should accept this answer if it worked for you so this question is marked as resolved